# How to open PDF created with flying-saucer/itext with a print dialog

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

*Some background to this question can be found at [Check printing with Java/JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435473/check-printing-with-java-jsp) and [Create a "print-only" PDF with itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638989/create-a-print-only-pdf-with-itext)*

I have been able to successfully create and open a PDF with a print dialog using iText-2.0.8 and the following code:

```
String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
writer.setOpenAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG)); 
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("TEST"));
document.close();
```

I have also been able to use flying-saucer to generate a PDF from XHTML using the following code:

```
String inputFile = "firstdoc.xhtml";
String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);

os.close();
```

However, I can't seem to get the two to work together...

I would like to create the PDF using flying-saucer as in the 2nd code block **and** I would like to set the open action of that PDF to `PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG`.

How can I get these two sets of code to work together such that a flying-saucer created PDF opens with a print dialog initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

In case someone else needs this in the future, you can just use PdfStamper to modify a PDF that has already been created.

Here's the full code that worked for me:

```
import java.io.*;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfAction;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FirstDoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        String inputFile = "firstdoc.xhtml";
        String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
        String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);

        os.close();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(outputFile);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("firstdocprint.pdf"));
        stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG), 1); 
        stamper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your post helped me solve my problem. However there is no need to create the 2nd PDF file, if the only thing you want is to print the PDF. I did below to avoid creating 2 PDFs:

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamForPrinter = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(os.toByteArray());
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStreamForPrinter);

Answer (score 3):

You can implement org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.PDFCreationListener of flying saucer and write your print dialog related code in preWrite(ITextRenderer iTextRenderer, int pageCount) method.

```
@Override    
public void preWrite(ITextRenderer iTextRenderer, int pageCount)
{
     iTextRenderer.getOutputDevice().getWriter().setOpenAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG));
}
```

Add this listener in ITextRenderer

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setListener(PDFCreationListener implemetation class);
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Modification to flying saucer document.

```
PDDocument document = ...;

PDPage firstPage = document.getPage(0);
PDPageAdditionalActions actions = firstPage.getActions();
actions.setO(new PDActionJavaScript("this.print(true);\r")); // O for open
```