# iText/flying-saucer PdfStamper using an OutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, itext, flying-saucer

I'm almost there (I think) on being able to render a PDF with a servlet without saving it first.  I've been able to successfully set it up, but I'm stuck at trying to make the PDF open in the client's browser with a Print Dialog initially.

I've been able to send my PDF to the client successfully with the following:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString())); 

OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream(); 

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(); 
renderer.setDocument(doc, null); 
renderer.layout(); 
renderer.createPDF(os); 

os.close();
```

But, I'm not sure how to put a print dialog on open of it.
I've used this code for a **physical** PDF file, but I need to be able to read the contents of the OutputStream in as a byte array for input to the PdfReader (I think):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("a_physical_file.pdf"); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os); 
stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG), 1); 
stamper.close();
```

Not sure how to do this with an OutputStream rather than an actual file...

I've also created an iText chat room if you would like to post there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8945/itext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning : I use an old version of Itext, so my experience may not be applicable.

PdfReader can use a byte array. so you could use a ByteArrayOutputStream as your first output stream, then use it to get the reader, instead of a filename.

Regards

*Edit : Regarding your question :*

i'm doing it the others way around : i'm working on a ByteArrayOutputStream and then writing it in the response stream :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// creating / modifying the pdf
...
byte[] pdfoutput = out.toByteArray();
res.setContentLength(pdfoutput.length);
res.getOutputStream().write(pdfoutput);
```

*Edit 2 : the final solution (from the chat room)*

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString())); 

OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(); 
renderer.setDocument(doc, null); 
renderer.layout(); 
renderer.createPDF(os); 
os.close(); 

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(((ByteArrayOutputStream)os).toByteArray()); 
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out); 
stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG), 1); 
stamper.close(); 

resp.getOutputStream().write(((ByteArrayOutputStream)out).toByteArray());
```

Comment: I've been looking into using ByteArrayOutputStream, but I am having trouble figuring out how to take `resp.getOutputStream()` and convert it into a ByteArrayOutputStream.  Are you familiar with how to go about doing that?

Comment: I'd like to do it in that way, but flying-saucer is using OutputStream for all of it's rendering.  I guess I'm really looking to see how I can take that OutputStream after `renderer.createPDF(os);` and convert it into a format that the PdfReader can read it (byte[], InputStream or URL from what I can see).  I've read up on converting an OutputStream to an InputStream, but I'm confused on how to actually implement it.  Would you mind joining me in chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8945/itext?

Comment: Hey I can't find the class PdfReader, where did they put it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PdfStamper, why don't you implement PDFCreationListener of flyingsacuer to massage any pdf created. You can get the PdfWriter instance and set the print dialogue from within the implementation class.

From the javadoc of PDFCreationListener

> PDFCreationListener is the callback listener for PDF creation. To use this, call  ITextRenderer.setListener(PDFCreationListener).Note that with a handle on the ITextRenderer instance (provided in the callback arguments) you can access the com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter instance being used to create the document, using
>   ITextRenderer.getOutputDevice(), then calling ITextOutputDevice.getWriter().

The related thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672012/how-to-open-pdf-created-with-flying-saucer-itext-with-a-print-dialog/16434192#16434192).